# Android Parse.com How to obtain name from Listview click event

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener

I am unable to figure out how to obtain the name or id from the listView that is populated from parse.com. I set it up to use the store object, but I am unable to access any of its methods. What do I need to do, to get this functional?

Store object

```js
@ParseClassName("Store")
public class Store extends ParseObject{

    public Store() {

    }

 public String getStoreName() {
        return getString("storeName");
 }

 public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
        put("storeName", storeName);
 }

    public ParseFile getPhotoFile() {
        return getParseFile("imgStore");
    }

    public void setPhotoFile(ParseFile file) {
        put("imgStore", file);
    }
}
```

Adapter

```js
public class MainListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Store> {

 public MainListAdapter(Context context) {
  // Specification of which stores to display
  super(context, new QueryFactory<Store>() {
   public ParseQuery create() {
    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Store");
                query.whereExists("storeName");
    return query;
   }
  });
 }

    @Override
 public View getItemView(Store object, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
  if (v == null) {
   v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.listview_mainpage, null);
  }

  super.getItemView(object, v, parent);

  // Add and download the image
  ParseImageView storeImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgStore);
  ParseFile imageFile = object.getPhotoFile();
  if (imageFile != null) {
            storeImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            storeImage.loadInBackground();
  }

  // Add the title view
  TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewStoreTitle);
  titleTextView.setText(object.getStoreName());

  return v;
 }

}
```

Onclick listener

```js
        adapter = new MainListAdapter(getActivity());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                String selectedFromList = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().toString()); //What do I place here to get access to the storeName or what do I have to do to obtain the correct id/storeName
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("myString", selectedFromList);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        adapter.loadObjects();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getClass` is not what you want in your listener.   I think you want to cast the item to the class `Store`.

Instead of this --

```
String selectedFromList = (listView.getItemAtPosition(position).getClass().toString());
```

you want something like --

```
Store selectedStore = (Store) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
String selectedFromList = selectedStore.getName();  // Or whatever method you need
```